# Linux counting words in random characters

Tags: linux

I have generated a file of random characters for A-Z and a-z, the file has different sizes for example 10000 characters or 1000000 I would like to search in them how many times the word 'cat' or 'dog' appeared Would someone be able to provide the command linux grep... | wc... or any other command that can handle this task.

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` has a `-c` command that will count the number of matches found.

So

```
grep -c "cat\|dog" <file name>
```

add `-i` if you want a case insensitive count

Answer (score 0):

You can use **grep** with the flag `-o`. For example:

```sh
grep -o "dog\|cat" <filename> | wc -l
```

About the flag `-o`, according to `man grep`: «Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such  part  on  a  separate  output line.»

This solution will work in several situations: multiple lines, a single line, the word surrounded with whitespaces or other characters, etc.

Comment: It works thank you, I would still like to ask if you know how to find the longest expansion of the number pi in a file with only random numbers?

Comment: There are a lot of ways. I'm not an expert of it, but you can try to implement the Gregory-Leibniz series in C, Rust or Golang. In bash, you can try this: `echo "scale=10; 4*a(1)" | bc -l`. The number 10 is the decimals number.

Comment: @kacper11312, did it solve your question?